# Oracle COALESCE or NVL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, coalesce

I have a stored procedure and I want to update a value in a table with the SYSDATE only if a parameter is NOT NULL.

In the following SQL, I want to set SYSENDDATE to NULL if pETime IS NULL Otherwise to SYSDATE

```
UPDATE OLCACT SET 
    ENDDATE    = pETime, 
    SYSENDDATE = SYSDATE, 
    GRD        = pGRD,
    PASS       = v_pass
```

Not sure how to use either NVL or COALESCE to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nvl2`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm) (yeah, "great" name, I know) will actually be much more convenient:

```
UPDATE OLCACT SET 
    ENDDATE    = pETime, 
    SYSENDDATE = NVL2(pETime, SYSDATE, NULL)
    GRD        = pGRD,
    PASS       = v_pass
```

Comment: I guess it should have been named IIF, huh?

Comment: @MB34 I'd settle for anything that doesn't have a digit in it :-)

Answer (score 5):

As @Mureinik suggests, `nvl2` is a perfectly valid way of doing this.  Even though this is a built-in function, it's not particularly well named or well known so I tend to avoid it.  It's way too easy to inadvertently read this as `nvl` or for someone to not recall exactly what that function does.  I would rather use a `CASE` statement that makes my intentions clear

```
UPDATE OLCACT SET 
    ENDDATE    = pETime, 
    SYSENDDATE = (CASE WHEN pETime IS NOT NULL
                       THEN sysdate
                       ELSE null
                   END)
    GRD        = pGRD,
    PASS       = v_pass
```

That's a bit more verbose than the `nvl2` option.  But it is more likely that a random developer looking at it in the future will be able to immediately understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `NVL2` or `CASE`:

```
UPDATE OLCACT SET 
    ENDDATE    = pETime, 
    SYSENDDATE = CASE
                   WHEN pETime IS NOT NULL 
                   THEN SYSDATE
                   ELSE NULL
                   END, 
    GRD        = pGRD,
    PASS       = v_pass
```